# How can I send a file from Linux to a Windows 10 folder with spaces in its name via scp?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, openssh, scp

Recently I have been testing the new OpenSSH feature in Windows 10, that allows me to send files from my linux to windows via scp, in general I have not had many difficult problems, but, trying to send files via scp, I have found the difficulty of sending files from Linux to Windows, if the destination folder has spaces in its name, that is:

```bsh
scp -r "Folder or file" <user>@<ip>:/Users/MyUser/Remote Folder
```

I tried:

```bsh
scp -r "Folder or file" <user>@<ip>:"/Users/MyUser/Remote Folder"
scp -r "Folder or file" <user>@<ip>:"/Users/MyUser/Remote\ Folder"
scp -r "Folder or file" <user>@<ip>:"/Users/MyUser/Remote\\\ Folder"
```

But with each of these commands, we get a **lost connection message**, but if they work from linux to linux.

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -p 22 "<user>@<ip>:/Users/MyUser/Remote Folder"`?

Comment: I had not tried, however it did not work. I also tried ```ssh -p 22 <user>@<ip>:"/Users/MyUser/Remote\040 Folder"```

Comment: I posted the command badly, it's not ssh, but scp, i.e ```scp -r <user>@<ip>:"/Users/MyUser/Remote\040 Folder" ```

Comment: Yes, I thought it looked weird.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1310833/425048)